# equivalent of _.isObject(value) -function in lodash

Tags: javascript, object, go, lodash

Is there any equivalent function in `go` for `_.isObject(value)` in `lodash`?

If not then how to implement in Go?

Comment: It needs more elaboration: what exactly do you have and what exactly do you want to type assert against?

Answer (score 2):

```golang
func isStruct(i interface{}) bool {
    return reflect.TypeOf(i).Kind() == reflect.Struct
}
```

You can test via changing type according to your needs such as reflect.Ptr. You can even get pointed value with reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(i)) after you ensured it's a pointer.

### Edit

`TypeOf(i)` would be the short version of `ValueOf(i).Type()` and is nicer to look at.

If you want to look deeper into this I recommend the reflect docs.
https://golang.org/pkg/reflect

Comment: Instead of `reflect.ValueOf(i).Type()` just use `reflect.TypeOf(i)`.